# Delete within transaction during error still occurs?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
   DELETE FROM TableA WHERE Col1 = 'someval'
   INSERT INTO TableB (col1,col2,col3,coln)
   SELECT col1,col2,col3,coln FROM SomeOtherTable

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I was running into a scenario where the Insert into failed due to some formatting issues, but I also noticed the Delete succeeded.  I thought the transaction would have prevented this?  What am I missing.  Obviously this is pseudo-code, but the real table names and code are nearly as simple.  What the heck could have lead to this?

I suppose one solution would be to add try/catch around the insert and rollback on error, but I was under the assumption that it would auto roll back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transaction simply means that any changes are *all committed* at the same time. If you encounter a non-batch aborting error then any prior changes (and any that occur afterwards) will still be committed when you reach the `COMMIT`.

For example, take the following table and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                            SomeDate date,
                            SomeString varchar(3));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (SomeDate, SomeString)
VALUES(GETDATE(),'abc'),
      (GETDATE(),'def'),
      (GETDATE(),'ghi');
GO
```

Now I'm going to `DELETE` and `INSERT` 2 rows, effecting 1 row with each operation inside a transaction. In one I'll provide an invalid date, an aborting error, and in the other a value that will cause truncation, a non-aborting error:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    DELETE FROM dbo.SomeTable
    WHERE ID = 1
    INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (SomeDate, SomeString)
    VALUES('20231301','xyz')
COMMIT;
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION
    DELETE FROM dbo.SomeTable
    WHERE ID = 2
    INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (SomeDate, SomeString)
    VALUES('20231201','mnop');
COMMIT;
GO
```

Notice the results you get back; `ID` `1` remains (batched aborted) but `ID` `2` doesn't (batch wasn't aborted):

| ID | SomeDate | SomeString |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-08-04 | abc |
| 3 | 2023-08-04 | ghi |
| 4 | 2023-08-04 | jkl |

If you want the transaction to be aborted when an error is encountered then use `XACT_ABORT`:

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION
    DELETE FROM dbo.SomeTable
    WHERE ID = 3
    INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (SomeDate, SomeString)
    VALUES('20231301','xyz')
COMMIT;
GO

SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION
    DELETE FROM dbo.SomeTable
    WHERE ID = 4
    INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (SomeDate, SomeString)
    VALUES('20231201','mnop');
COMMIT;
GO
```

Notice that `ID` `4` is not `DELETE`d now too.

Comment: thank you!  Will TRY/CATCH allow one to also avoid the delete from occurring if the insert fails?

Comment: On it's own, [no](https://dbfiddle.uk/iV6IK8XG) @bitshift , you'd need to also put a `ROLLBACK` into the `CATCH` and likely `THROW` the error. Why do all of that when you can tell the data engine to abort the entire current transaction on an error?